# Hide Dynamically Added Columns/Fields

Tags: javascript, dhtml

I have some dynamically created rows/columns.  What I'd like to do is set a section of it (txtOffsetID) to be hidden.  I tried this:    `txtOffsetID.setAttribute('type', 'hidden');` but it didn't work.  I want to hide that entire column and any new columns added. I need it to work in IE.  Thanks.

Sample code:

```
function addNewOffsetItem()
{
    var iX = document.getElementById("txtOffsetIndex").value;
    iX ++;
    document.getElementById("txtOffsetIndex").value = iX;

    var tbl = document.getElementById("tblOffsetDetail").getElementsByTagName("TBODY")[0];
    var tr = document.createElement("TR");
    tbl.appendChild(tr);

    //This section should be hidden.    
    //txtOffsetID1
    var tdID = document.createElement("TD");
    tr.appendChild(tdID);

    var p = document.createElement("P");
    tdID.appendChild(p);

    var txtOffsetID = document.createElement("input"); 
    p.appendChild(txtOffsetID);

    txtOffsetID.id = "txtOffsetID" + iX;
    txtOffsetID.setAttribute('name','txtOffsetID' + iX);
     **document.getElementById("colOffsetID").style.display="none";**

    //This section should be visible.
    //txtOffsetComments1 
    var tdComments = document.createElement("TD");
    tr.appendChild(tdComments);

    var p = document.createElement("P");
    tdComments.appendChild(p);

    var txtOffsetComments = document.createElement("textarea"); 
    p.appendChild(txtOffsetComments);

    txtOffsetComments.id = "txtOffsetComments" + iX;
    txtOffsetComments.setAttribute('name','txtOffsetComments' + iX);    
}

<table width="99%" border="1" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" id="tblOffsetDetail">
    <colgroup>
    <col id="colOffsetID">
    <col id="colOffsetComments">
    </colgroup>
    <tbody>     
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" id="txtOffsetID" name="txtOffsetID"></td>
            <td><p><textarea name="txtOffsetComments" cols="15" rows="3" id="txtOffsetComments"></textarea></p></td>        
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

created "tr" element can be hidden like this

```
tr.setAttribute('style', 'display: none;');
```

but in case you want to hide full column than you need to use colgroup table element
example

```
<table>
<colgroup>
<col id="colOne">
<col id="colTwo">
<col id="colThre">
</colgroup>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>one</td>
<td>two</td>
<td>three</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

you can hide colTwo like this

```
document.getElementById('colTwo').style.display = 'none';
```

I hope this helps